# BRP holder , spouse of British National, travel to Schengen

Tags: schengen-visas, uk-citizens

For a holiday,
I am a british national and passport holder, residing with my wife in the UK.
She holds an Indian passport with a British Resident Permit.(not a permanent resident or indefinite leave to remain)

My daughter has an american passport, she does not need a visa to travel to europe.

Can we travel to europe without a visa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wife needs a visa to enter the Schengen Area https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa_en (assuming that’s what you are referring to by ‘Europe’).